# jQuery adds a class but won't remove one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It adds the "extra-active" class and removes the "extra" class when you click an .extra anchor, but when you click an extra-active anchor it refuses to remove the extra-active class and replace it with extra.

Here's the HTML

```js
 $("a.extra").click(function(e){
  $(this).addClass("extra-active").removeClass("extra");
  e.preventDefault();
 })

 $("a.extra-active").click(function(e){
  $(this).removeClass("extra-active").addClass("extra");
  e.preventDefault();
 })
```

```css
.extra{
 display:inline-block;
 height: 128px;
 width: 128px;

 background-color:grey;
 padding:12px;
 border-radius:8px;
}

.extra-group{
 p {
  text-align:center;
 }
}


.extra:hover{
 background-color:blue;
}

.extra-active{
 display:inline-block;
 height: 128px;
 width: 128px;

 background-color:red !important;
 padding:12px;
 border-radius:8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="display:inline-block;">
 <span class="extra-group">
  <a class="extra" href="" title = "An hour of Ironing" id="extra-ironing" style = "background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='book-icons/iron-icon.png') }}'); background-size: 80% 80%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;"></a>
  <p>An Hours Ironing</p>
 </span>
 <span class="extra-group">
  <a class="extra" href="" title = "Inside the Fridge" id="extra-fridge"  style = "background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='book-icons/fridge-icon.png') }}'); background-size: 80% 80%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;"></a>
  <p>Inside the Fridge</p>
 </span>
 <span class="extra-group">
  <a class="extra" href="" title = "Inside the Oven" id="extra-oven"  style = "background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='book-icons/oven-icon.png') }}'); background-size: 80% 80%;; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;"></a>
  <p>Inside the Oven</p>
 </span>
 <span class="extra-group">
  <a class="extra" href="" title = "A load of Washing" id="extra-washing" style = "background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='book-icons/washer-icon.png') }}'); background-size: 80% 80%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;"></a>
  <p>A load of Washing</p>
 </span>
 <span class="extra-group">
  <a class="extra " href="" title = "Interior Windows" id="extra-windows" style = "background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='book-icons/window-icon.png') }}'); background-size: 80% 80%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;"></a>
  <p>Interior Windows</p>
 </span>
</span>
```

Comment: use `on` instead of `click` ... there are no elements with  `extra-active` when the code executes ...

Comment: Understanding [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) can help you understand why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Part of the reason is because your HTML is invalid. `<span>` elements can't contain `<p>` elements.

Comment: Thanks all for submissions, will look into event delegation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the initial html there isn't any `extra-active` class so when jquery binds `click` event on that class, it binds to nothing.
You should use `on` to bind event or re-bind the event after you add the class.

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'a.extra', function(e){
    $(this).addClass("extra-active").removeClass("extra");
    e.preventDefault();
})

$(document.body).on('click', 'a.extra-active', function(e){
   $(this).removeClass("extra-active").addClass("extra");
   e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Your idea to use `.on()` is correct but your syntax is wrong. Need to use the event delegation syntax. What you have now is functionally equivalent to what the OP has.

Comment: you are right, a wrong copy&paste from his question, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @xandercoded's contribution, I added a listener to the body and then updated the target of the on function.

```js
 $("body").on('click','.extra',function(e){
  $(e.target).addClass("extra-active").removeClass("extra");
  e.preventDefault();
 })

 $("body").on('click','.extra-active',function(e){
  $(e.target).removeClass("extra-active").addClass("extra");
  e.preventDefault();
 })
```

```css
.extra{
 display:inline-block;
 height: 128px;
 width: 128px;

 background-color:grey;
 padding:12px;
 border-radius:8px;
}

.extra-group{
 p {
  text-align:center;
 }
}


.extra:hover{
 background-color:blue;
}

.extra-active{
 display:inline-block;
 height: 128px;
 width: 128px;

 background-color:red !important;
 padding:12px;
 border-radius:8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="display:inline-block;">
 <span class="extra-group">
  <a class="extra" href="" title = "An hour of Ironing" id="extra-ironing" style = "background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='book-icons/iron-icon.png') }}'); background-size: 80% 80%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;"></a>
  <p>An Hours Ironing</p>
 </span>
 <span class="extra-group">
  <a class="extra" href="" title = "Inside the Fridge" id="extra-fridge"  style = "background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='book-icons/fridge-icon.png') }}'); background-size: 80% 80%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;"></a>
  <p>Inside the Fridge</p>
 </span>
 <span class="extra-group">
  <a class="extra" href="" title = "Inside the Oven" id="extra-oven"  style = "background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='book-icons/oven-icon.png') }}'); background-size: 80% 80%;; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;"></a>
  <p>Inside the Oven</p>
 </span>
 <span class="extra-group">
  <a class="extra" href="" title = "A load of Washing" id="extra-washing" style = "background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='book-icons/washer-icon.png') }}'); background-size: 80% 80%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;"></a>
  <p>A load of Washing</p>
 </span>
 <span class="extra-group">
  <a class="extra " href="" title = "Interior Windows" id="extra-windows" style = "background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='book-icons/window-icon.png') }}'); background-size: 80% 80%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;"></a>
  <p>Interior Windows</p>
 </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only $("a.extra") find elements when it runs so that is the only onclick that will execute.

$("a.extra-active").click function will never execute because if doesn't find any elements with that class when it runs.

If you only want to change classes you can use toggle in your $("a.extra").onclick

```
$(this).toggleClass("extra-active");
$(this).toggleClass("extra");
```

Answer (score 0):

I realy don't know why you need to replace classes while you can just use **toggleClass();**

in css

```
.extra{
    display:inline-block;
    height: 128px;
    width: 128px;

    background-color:grey !important;
    padding:12px;
    border-radius:8px;
}

.extra-group > p {
        text-align:center;
}


.extra:hover{
    background-color:blue;
}

.extra-active{
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

in js

```
$("a.extra").click(function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass("extra-active");
        e.preventDefault();
    })
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/xLxthut1/)

Answer (score 0):

When you reference `$("a.extra-active")` there are none so no handlers are attached. Even after you create them your javascript has already run.

Try using event propagation.

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.extra-active', function() {
    // Do Work
});
```

This way if you click the document it checks to see if the clicked element matches `.extra-active`. If it does it runs the function.

[More reading](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Answer (score 0):

Try toggling the 2 classes. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehn4ofh0/)

```
$("a.extra").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
$(this).toggleClass('extra');
$(this).toggleClass('extra-active');


});

$("a.extra-active").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
$(this).toggleClass('extra');
$(this).toggleClass('extra-active');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, there are no `.extra-active`s when the code first loads.

This will work:

```
var extraActiveClickFunction = function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("extra-active").addClass("extra");
    e.preventDefault();
}
var extraClickFunction = function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("extra-active").addClass("extra");
    e.preventDefault();
    // this ensures that our newly created extra-active class 
    // has the correct function bound
    $("a.extra-active").click(extraActiveClickFunction)
}

// original page load bind
$("a.extra").click(extraClickFunction)
```

The benefits of assigning functions to variables is shown here too, it makes this sort of thing much easier to handle